# Vue Router not displaying template

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to get a Vue Router working in my Vue app. When I click the link it just reloads the page and doesn't show the Dashboard template. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

This is what I have in my main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VModal from 'vue-js-modal'
import TreeView from "vue-json-tree-view"
import '@/assets/css/tailwind.css'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import store from './store.js'

Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.use(Vuex)
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(VModal)
Vue.use(TreeView)



let Dashboard = require('./components/Dashboard.vue');
let Home = require('./components/LandingPage.vue');



const routes = [{
  path: '/',
  component: Home
},
{
  path: '/dasboard',
  name: Dashboard,
  component: Dashboard
}
];

const router = new VueRouter
({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
})

Vue.use(VueRouter)

new Vue({
  store,
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

In my LandingPage.vue file I have this link:

```
<router-link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</router-link>
```

My Dashboard.vue file is a simple template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your routes should be defined as this

```
const routes = [{
  path: '/',
  component: Home
},
{
  path: '/dashboard',
  name: 'dashboard',
  component: Dashboard
}
];
```

In your LandingPage.vue file write:

```
<router-link :to="{name:'dashboard'}">Dashboard</router-link>
```

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo in the routes:

```
path: '/dasboard',
```

Also, `name` for a route expects a string, not the component.